# xpath in firebug works however sendkey is not sending value

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I am trying to write a login code for hotmail. I asked this a few days ago on how to get the xpath, someone answered and gave me the correct xpath in his reply:

```
//*[@id='CredentialsInputPane']//div[3]//div[2]/div
```

His answer worked.

Today I tried to come up with my own xpath solution and in Firepath when I use the following syntax it highlights the user name field.

```
//div[contains(@class,'placeholder has-focus')][text()='Email, phone, or Skype name']
```

Question/problem: When I run the test, in UI it does not send the value user@msn.com, it clicks the Next button and I get error "Please enter a value".

What is wrong with my xpath syntax, even though it is highlighting the field? Why is it not sending the email id?

Code:

```
driver.get("https://login.live.com/login.srf?");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'placeholder')][text()='Email, phone, or Skype name']")).sendKeys("usertest81@msn.com");

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@id,'idSIButton9')]")).click();
```

Thanks in advance for your time and explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to send value to a non-input field. This may be the reason. Try with the following-

```
driver.findElement(By.name("loginfmt")).sendKeys("usertest81@msn.com");
```

Comment: <div class="placeholder" data-bind="text: hintText, css: hintCss" style="cursor:text" aria-hidden="true">Email, phone, or Skype name</div>

Based on what firebug is showing above for the field,how did you get loginfmt?

Comment: just checked for input fields in the inspected window.

Comment: Thanks, I suppose next time I should check for input 1st  using //input before writing the xpath syntax.